# How do I specify @param @return for object type in Google Closure Compiler?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

In javascript code, I have this function

```
/*
 * @param 
 * @return
 */
foo = function (oObjFoo) {
      // do something
      return oObjBar;
}
```

oObjFoo is type : {"a":number, "b":text, "c": bool }

oObjBar is type : {"c":number, "d":text }

How do I specify the @param, @return to do much stricter type check with the google closure compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/**
 * @param {{a:number, b:string, c: boolean }} oObjFoo
 * @return {{c:number, d:string}}
 */
var foo = function (oObjFoo) {
  // do something
  return oObjBar;
}
```

Note that the comment must start with a double asterisk for the compiler to count it as a JsDoc comment.

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect for what I needed.    If I have more rep, I will upvote it also.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at JSDoc:

http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html

```
/**
 * @param {Object} oAttributes
 * @param {namespace.extension=} oAttributes.parent DOC-Description
 * @param {jQuery=} oAttributes.$element Optional jQuery-Element
 */
```